# What is the view of Vedanta sect on yoga and sankhya?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, yoga, sankhya

I have heard that in the vedanta sutras there is some criticism about yoga and sankhya sects.

However in geeta we find that yoga is the main.subject and there are also chapters like sankhya yoga.

Both of these are.prime texts.of vedanta

So what is the overall view of vedanta on yoga and sankhya ?

Do.geeta and vedanta sutras have mutual agreement on yoga and sankhya ?

Comment: @UdayKrishna because it is a sect with specific ideologies and followers.

Answer (score 2):

Shankara criticizes Samkhya in his Brahma-Sutra Bhasya. His main points of criticism are:

- I.1.5-11 and 18: Samkhya considers an unconscious prakriti as origin and source of the material world, while Brahman is omniscient as the source of the world according to sruti.
- I.4.1-28: Samkhya wrongly interprets sruti.
- II.1.1-11: Samkhya wrongly interprets smrti.
- II.2.1-10: Samkhya argues in an erroneous way.

A clear exposition of Shankara's critique is given by "Larson, Gerald James: Classical Samkhya. An Interpretation of its history and Meaning. Motilal Barnasidas, Delhi 2011." The chapter "Epilogue" classifies Shankara's critique according to the four issues above and expands each in some detail.

Comment: What about yoga

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi I do not know about an explicit critique of Shankara specifically on Yoga. In my opinion, Yoga - citta vRtti nirodhaH - is a method of meditation which relies on Samkhya as its philosophical basis.

Comment: please also go thru my posts on sankara and vedanta..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Actually the same arguments against Samkhya also apply to Yoga.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury so you mean samkhya and yoga are essentially same philosophy ?